# How to select particular item from a custom list view

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have used  listview to display the name,description and department of a company which works fine.but i want to select a particular item that is description and department from the list view and pass it to two different fragments which is displayed in a viewpager.
 But i don't know how to select only the description and pass it to the corresponding fragment and the department item to the department fragment.

Class file showing listview:

```
public class CompanyAct extends AppCompatActivity{
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/2ggcs";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Company> companydetails = new ArrayList<Company>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.companyprimarydetails);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.companylist);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, companydetails);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);


                             Company company=new Company();
                           // Company company = new Company(obj.getInt("companyID"),obj.getString("comapnyName"),obj.getString("companyOwner"),obj.getString("companyStartDate"),obj.getString("companyDescription"),departments);
                            company.setCompanyid(obj.getInt("companyID"));
                            company.setCompanyname(obj.getString("comapnyName"));
                            company.setCompanyowner(obj.getString("companyOwner"));
                            company.setStartdate(obj.getString("companyStartDate"));
                            company.setDescription(obj.getString("companyDescription"));
                            company.setDepartments(obj.getString("companyDepartments"));

                            companydetails.add(company);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter:**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Company> companyItems;
Company m;
Context context;
public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Company> companyItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.companyItems = companyItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return companyItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return companyItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.companyprimaryitems, null);

    TextView companyid=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.companyid);
    TextView companyname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companyname);
    TextView companyowner = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companyowner);
    TextView companystartdate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comapnystartdate);
    TextView comapnydesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companydesc);
    TextView companylists=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.comapanylists);

     m = companyItems.get(position);



    companyid.setText(String.valueOf(m.getCompanyid()));
    companyname.setText(m.getCompanyname());
    companyowner.setText(m.getCompanyowner());
    companystartdate.setText(m.getStartdate());
    comapnydesc.setText(m.getDescription());

    //rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));


   /* String departments = "";
    for (String str : m.getDepartments()) {
        departments += str + ", ";
    }
    departments = departments.length() > 0 ? departments.substring(0,
            departments.length() - 2) : departments; */
    companylists.setText(m.getDepartments());
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            m=companyItems.get(position);
            String des=m.getDescription()+"#"+m.getDepartments();
            Intent i=new Intent(context,DetailsActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("key", des);
            i.putExtras(bundle);
           context.startActivity(i);


          //  DescriptionFragment fragobj = new DescriptionFragment();
          //  fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
           // Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
          //  intent.putExtra("description", m.getDescription());
          //  intent.putExtra("department", m.getDepartments());
           // context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // release year


    return convertView;
}
```

**FragmentActivity:**

```
    public class DetailsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    String receivingdata;
    CharSequence Titles[]={"Description","Departments"};
    int Numboftabs =2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slidingpanel);       
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);

        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    }
}
```

**DescriptionFragment:**

```
 public class DescriptionFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.description_frag, container, false);
      //  String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");

        TextView desc=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvdescription);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
    public static DescriptionFragment newInstance(String text) {

        DescriptionFragment f = new DescriptionFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }
}
```

**Department Fragment:**

```
public class DepartmentsFragment extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.description_frag, container, false);
    TextView dept=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvdepartments);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
public static DepartmentsFragment newInstance(String text) {

    DepartmentsFragment f = new DepartmentsFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}
```

I have even tried to pass the values from customadapter to the fragmentactivity but it didn't works showing null pointer exception.I would like to know how to select a particular item from the list and pass it to two different fragments.

Comment: get onClick method on your textview in getview adapter and pass your data using fragment using setArguments(). And get that data in another fragment using getArguments().

Comment: When asking questions on StackOverflow, please make a [mcve], thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goto your adapter and in getview method you just set the onclick listner to the description text like

```
comapnydesc.setOnClickListner(new .....)
```

Thanks.